# Sliding Menu with Fragments performance issue

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, slidingmenu

I am using SLiding menu at My App and according to menu item , I am changing always the fragment at activity which have binded already to menu. But There is performance issue. it is freezing when i am attaching the fragments. but after the wiew created. the performance is normal. I am replacing the fragments after call the toggle function at menu.

is there anyone to have any opinion about it ?

Comment: How do you attach the fragments? Do they get removed from the stack upon dismissal? Also do you use the `View Holder` pattern for inflating your sliding menu? Does the freezing occures in the beginning or after a little while?

Comment: freezing is occuring when it is openning.

Comment: You have to post the code that handles the onClick event and opens the fragment and the code of the fragment itself so that we can see what is going on on the inflation/rendering

Answer (score 0):

just call it as:

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Pass the event to ActionBarDrawerToggle, if it returns
    // true, then it has handled the app icon touch event

    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.evnetCalender) {

        if (!isToggle) {
            item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_view_list_white_24dp);
            setFragment(caldroidCalendarFragment);
            isToggle = true;

        } else {
            item.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_event_white_24dp);
            setFragment(scheduleEventFragment);
            isToggle = false;

        }


    }
```

and set your fragment when you toggle it

```
private void setFragment(Fragment fragment1) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction =
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content, fragment1);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
}
```

this content identifier is your frame layout id in which your fragment take place